# TYPO3 gridelements: appearance layout not showing correctly

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-10.x, tx-gridelements

I am using TYPO3 10.4 and Gridelements with Dataprocessing. Everything is working fine, except the appearance / layout option for content elements I place in the Gridcontainer.

I have defined a `TCEFORM.tt_content` Layout which I then give a custom class in my Typoscript:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.outerWrap {
  cObject = CASE
  cObject {
    key.field = layout

    default = TEXT
    default.value = |

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = <div class="customClass">|</div>
  }
}
```

As long as I use appearance Layout outside a gridelements container it works fine a "customClass" is wrapped around the element.

As soon as I try to use it inside a gridelement, the additional wrapper is not rendered. How do I get the stdWrap passed through in Gridelements?

My gridelements configuration is

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
  templateRootPaths {
      15 = path/to/templates/gridelements/
  }

  dataProcessing {
    10 {
      default {
        options {
            resolveFlexFormData = 1
              resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the template file:

```
<div class="column2 frame-layout-{data.layout} {f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}" id="c{data.uid}">
    <f:if condition="{children}">
        <f:for each="{children.1}" as="column" key="columnNumber">
            <div id="c{data.uid}-{columnNumber}" class="grid-column grid-column-{columnNumber} col-lg-6">
                <f:for each="{column}" as="child">
                    <f:render partial="Child"
                        arguments="{data: child.data, children: child.children, options: options, settings: settings}" />
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:if>
</div>
```

EDIT: I found a working way with conditions in the template files: `<f:if condition="{child.data.layout} == 1">` and depending on that wrap the div with my customClass around the children. But that seems kinda messy and complicated.

Comment: It's not messy... setting layout relevant code in Fluid is the new world. If you are using FSC (or own CEs based on Fluid), you should put all cases in your templates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, maybe not "messy" but still seems a bit complicated. But at least I know now that this is how it's supposed to be.

Comment: One of Fluid's goals was to control the frontend output in the template as long as it concerns *layout* decisions. A mixture of layout decisions in the template and TypoScript makes it confusing - and may require more / different know-how. Often you can teach a frontend developer Fluid, but TypoScript rather requires an understanding of programming and is more likely to be sought from the integrator or backend developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put that "wrap" into a Fluid layout file and then fetch the rest of the content from the Fluid template file using sections and a layout switch.

This way you put the layout information into the file it's supposed and expected to be.

To switch between different layouts you can then use a dynamic call within the template file instead of a switch viewhelper:

```
<f:layout name="Layout{layout}" />
```

This way you keep the code lean and layout and content rendering separated, which comes close to the principle of TypoScript "wraps".